# How to use bind param in codeigniter in mysql IN operator

Tags: mysql

Below is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sku` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sk_val` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `sku` (`id`, `sk_val`, `date_time`) VALUES
(3, '[removed]alert&#40;'xss'&#41;;[removed]', '2017-04-12 12:58:38'),
(4, '[removed]alert&#40;'xss'&#41;;[removed]', '2017-04-12 13:46:34');
```

I am using CI framework. When I try to fetch data from the `sku` table it return false. Below is my code.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM sku WHERE sk_val IN (?)";
$result = $this->db->query($query, array("[removed]alert&#40;'xss'&#41;;[removed]"));
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `FIND_IN_SET(field_name,param)` instead of `IN(param)`? Normally, FIND_IN_SET works like a charm with param. You can then write your query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM sku WHERE FIND_IN_SET(sk_val,?);
$result = $this->db->query($query, array("[removed]alert&#40;\'xss\'&#41;;[removed]"));
```

Hope this helps.